# Android - ExpandableListView expand by clicking anywhere in row

Tags: android, expandablelistview

At the moment the `ExpandableListView` I have implemented is expanded using the default functionality of clicking the arrow located to the far left of each row.

I need to change it so that it expands when the user clicks anywhere on the row.

Many thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code and maybe elaborate on what you've tried, how it failed, etc.